# My PowerPoint document properties keep reverting when I save the file

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

My PowerPoint document properties keep reverting when I save the file

I am experience a strange issue. I am on SharePoint online and I have a SharePoint library with several columns to that I update the document metadata/properties (manually or by a power automate flow).
However from today for some reason, after I have updated the document metadata/properties, if I open the file and let it auto-save or even if I do change something in it and save it, all the recent metadata/properties gets wiped and those that remain get overwritten with the default/previous old values.

Through investigating this, I am pretty sure it isn't being caused by a rouge power automate flow as I turned them all off and it still did it. I think it has retained a value on the actual PowerPoint file property and this is what overwrites what's been updated on the column on the SharePoint library. This happens immediately after saving.

The scenario is as follows:

1. I created a document and uploaded to SharePoint and updated Metadata/field named "Status" to Pending.
2. From SharePoint I opened the file in desktop application, did some modification in the file content and saved it. No modification were done in Metadata fields of the document.
3. I started a flow which updated the "Status" field to Approved.
4. Again from SharePoint I opened the file in desktop application, did some modifications in the file content but no modification were done in Metadata fields of the document and saved it. Here the problem started, when I saved the file it reverted "Status" field value to Pending. This should not happen.

Any help to resolve this? As I need the updated columns to remain as they are unless changed either manually or by a flow.

I am using:
SharePoint Online,
Office 365

Edit 1:

1. Yes, "Status" column is a custom column.
2. "Status" is choice type of column and values are Not Started, Pending, Approved and Rejected.
3. Trigger of flow is For a selected file. I have turned off the flow but still this issue is occurring. So, I have concluded that there is no issue with the flow.
4. Yes, version history is enabled. Below is the screenshot of version history. Please note that in version 23 the property CPM/PM Status and Due Date gets reverted when user saves the file.

[image: Version History]

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm some information to troubleshoot the issue.

1.Whether this "Status" column is a custom column？

2.What is type of this "Status" column?

3.What is the trigger of flow? Could you provide some screenshots of the flow?

4.Whether the version history enable in the document library? Could you provide some screenshots of the version history?

[image]

Comment: Hi Emily Du, Below are the details as requested:
1. Yes, "Status" column is a custom column.
2. "Status" is choice type of column and values are Not Started, Pending, Approved and Rejected.
3. Trigger of flow is For a selected file. I have turned off the flow but still this issue is occurring. So, I have concluded that there is no issue with the flow.
4. Yes, version history is enabled.

Comment: Hi Emily Du, I have added more details in the question. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you edit file in online then compare the result?

Comment: When I edit in online word browser it works fine. We only have an issue when we try to edit the file using desktop Word App.

Comment: I have tested the scenario you provided and cannot reproduce the issue. You could try to uninstall then install the word client application. If the issue persists, I suggest you open a service request to get remote help.

Comment: Even I am not able to reproduce it but few of the company’s employees are facing this issue. Can you please give me a link where can I open a service request.

Comment: Please go to 365 admin center -> Support -> New service request. Add a screenshot in the answer.